# Calculations and sorting in background thread took too much time to finish in swift 4

Tags: swift, sorting, background, realm, calculation

Which part of the swift lifecycle should I put my calculations and sorting block of code? Should I put it on **override func loadView** or in **viewDidLoad** , or I just missing something that caused of the delay of the result.

This is my calculation and sorting block of code which I put inside **override func loadView()**

```
    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()
        print("loadView")

     searchBar.rx.text.orEmpty.debounce(0.3, scheduler:ConcurrentDispatchQueueScheduler.init(qos: .userInteractive))
    .map({ (data) ->ThreadSafeReference<Results<TrialCourtBranches>> in
         autoreleasepool{
            let realm = try! Realm()

            var removeSpaceName = ""
            var removeSpaceStation = ""
            let jr_separated_text = jr_text?.split(separator: "-",maxSplits: 1)



     if !(jr_text?.isEmpty)!{
     removeSpaceName = jr_separated_text[0].trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)
     removeSpaceStation = jr_sep`enter code here`arated_text![1].trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)
                    }
     let tcb_predicate_filter = NSPredicate(format: "(tc.tc_filter == true) AND (jr.jr_name LIKE[c] %@ AND jr.station LIKE[c] %@) AND ((loc.pc.province LIKE[c] %@) AND (loc.pc.city_municipality LIKE[c] %@))","\(removeSpaceName)*","\(removeSpaceStation)*","\(pro_text!)*","\(city_text!)*")

     let tcb_predicate = NSPredicate(format: "(branch_name LIKE[c] %@) OR (jr.jr_name LIKE[c] %@) OR (office_no LIKE[c] %@) OR (judge.name LIKE[c] %@) OR (tc.tc_code LIKE[c] %@) OR (tc.tc_type LIKE[c] %@) OR (loc.pc.city_municipality LIKE[c] %@) OR (loc.pc.province LIKE[c] %@) OR (loc.address1 LIKE[c] %@) OR (email_address LIKE[c] %@)","*\(data)*","*\(data)*","*\(data))*","*\(data)*","*\(data)*","*\(data)*","*\(data)*","*\(data)*","*\(data)*","*\(data)*")

     var tcb:Results<TrialCourtBranches>?
     var tcb_safe:ThreadSafeReference<Results<TrialCourtBranches>>?

         if (self.tcb_filteredArray2?.isEmpty)! == false{
             self.tcb_filteredArray2?.removeAll()
         }
   tcb = realm.objects(TrialCourtBranches.self).filter(tcb_predicate).filter(tcb_pr 
   edicate_filter)

   if (CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() == 
    true) && (self.locationManager.location?.coordinate != nil){

        if (distanceList?.isEmpty)! == false{
            distanceList?.removeAll()
            distanceResult?.removeAll()
        }
   }
    for court in tcb!{ 
       self.tcb_filteredArray2?.append(court.tc_branchid)

       if (CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() == 
       true) && (self.locationManager.location?.coordinate != nil){
           let dis = sortDistance(id: court.tc_branchid, 
       lat: court.loc?.lat, long: court.loc?.lng)
           distanceList?.append(dis)
       }
    }
    tcb_safe = ThreadSafeReference(to: tcb!)

    return tcb_safe!
    }
    })
    .observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
    .subscribe(onNext: { (data_safe) in

    if (self.tcb_filteredArray2?.isEmpty)! == false{
       self.count = (self.tcb_filteredArray2?.count)!
       self.entries.text = "\(self.count) Entries"
       self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async {
if (CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() == 
    true) && (self.locationManager.location?.coordinate != nil){

  let realm = try! Realm()
  for dis in distanceList!{
     let from = CLLocation(latitude: dis.lat!,longitude: dis.long!)
     let distanceFromUser = self.locationManager.location?.distance(from: from)
     let newResultDistance = resultDistance(id: dis.id!, distance: distanceFromUser)
     distanceResult?.append(newResultDistance)
  }
  distanceResult?.sort(by: { (distance1, distance2) -> Bool in
    return (distance1.distance!) <= (distance2.distance!)
  })
  if (self.tcb_filteredArray2?.isEmpty)! == false{
        self.tcb_filteredArray2?.removeAll()
  }
  for res in distanceResult!{
    let tcb = realm.objects(TrialCourtBranches.self).filter("tc_branchid == %@",res.id!)

    self.tcb_filteredArray2?.append((tcb.first?.tc_branchid)!)
  }
}
     DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
     }
  }

  }, onError: { (errorResult) in
     print(errorResult)
  }, onCompleted: {
     print("onCompleted")
  }, onDisposed: {
     print("onDisposed")
  })
  .disposed(by: bag)
  }
```

Just to be clear , this is the specific part of the calculation and 
    sorting

```
**Calculations**

for dis in distanceList!{
    let from = CLLocation(latitude: dis.lat!, longitude: dis.long!)
    let distanceFromUser = self.locationManager.location?.distance(from: from)
    let newResultDistance = resultDistance(id: dis.id!, distance: distanceFromUser)
    distanceResult?.append(newResultDistance)
}

**Sorting**

distanceResult?.sort(by: { (distance1, distance2) -> Bool in
   return (distance1.distance!) <= (distance2.distance!)
})
```

Any suggestion or help will be appreciated. I'm just new in swift 4.

Comment: please post some code what kind of calculations you are doing?

Comment: @RahulGUsai edited post